# variable reference and mutability

Tags: python-2.7, immutability, object-reference, mutability

I've found many articles providing examples like the following:

```
listA = [0]
listB = listA
listB.append(1)
print listA
print listB
```

The gaol is to show that both lists are pointing to the same object, then if that object is changed, both lists display that change. In fact:

```
print listA is listB
```

displays True...So far so good.

However, I cannot figure out why the following example does not work as the previous one.

```
listA = [1, 2, 3]
max_val = max(listA)

print max_val is listA[-1]  # True

max_val = 10

print max_val is listA[-1] # False
```

so the list is not changed even though max_val is pointing to the last element of the list.

Why is that ?